# How to change the color of ActivityIndicator in Xamarin.Forms MacOs?

Tags: macos, colors, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

I have the following code:

```
ActivityIndicator activityIndicator = new ActivityIndicator
        {
            Color = Color.LightGreen,
            IsVisible = true,
            IsRunning = true,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        };
```

It works normal on Android, iOs, UWP, but on MAC there is an extrange issue, it shows normal the first time that the ActivityIndicator shows:

[image]

But the second time it looks with a different color (Black) all the ActivityIndicators of the App, Any Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting it globally ?

**App.xaml**

```
<prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="ActivityIndicator" TargetType="ActivityIndicator">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="IsRunning" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Setter Property="Color" Value="Color.LightGreen" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
```

Comment: LeRoy I tried this today, unfortunatelly I got the same result, first time green, second time black.